# Getting a single element from a list of lists in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list

So I have a list of ObjectA in hibernate. ObjectA contains a list of ObjectB.

I want to display ObjectA.title along with ObjectB.rank for a given ObjectB.year.

What I do now, is that I iterate over the first list (ObjectA) and get the title. Then I iterate the second list (ObjectB) to get the correct rank for the specified year.

Because both lists can be quite large, this takes a while. Is there any way to speed up the fetching, by having hibernate only get one row from the second list instead of going through each of them and checking the year?

Comment: Please show your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could if you have a bi-directional relation from ObjectB back to ObjectA. 
See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional

Then you could do an HQL:

```
select b.rank, a.title from ObjectB b join b.a a where b.year=... and a.id=...
```